# Flex display pictures in div not fully responsive and do not extend to full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having issues getting the 2 pictures in .iv1 and .iv2 fully responsive.

They are not displayed in the JS and sorry for the semi minified css code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjpzgcd8/1/

```
<div class="picwrap">
 <div class="iv1" ><img src="" alt="24 Stunden Taxi"></div>
```

This is still the mobile first build up, everything is nicely responsive, but i think i am missing the elephant in the room here.

On the 3rd line is the setting for the img tag, but it does not work, i have tried background: cover and everything which came to mind, but nothing worked so far.

Wrapper for the pics is on line 21 and the divs are on line 30 and 31 in the css file.

Thanks for any help

Comment: PS, it is all repsonsive up to 320px width.

Answer (score 0):

Add to .iv1 and .iv2 for container responsibility:

```
{right: 2%;}
```

And to img, without it it works only for 320px and less:

```
{width: 100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjpzgcd8/2/

Comment: Can you please explain why the img would only work to 320px with the previous code? I am currently practicing the flex layouts, while the main basics are very simple, there is some stuff which is entirely different, like margins etc.

Comment: I was wrong at this point. I thought image size was 320px and will work with max-size: 100%; Currently I don't see any responsibility in your fiddle.

Comment: Nah, you have it right, i did not update the fiddle yet, i went straight to my text editor.The image size is indeed 300px wide, but i did not declare that anywhere in the code.